# Move one item down in <nav> tag but keep the same layout for the rest

Tags: html, css

Hi I am making a navigation bar and all the items are in a  tag. But I want one item what is also in this nav tag to be at the button om the navigation bar without changing the rest of the layout.

But what happends when I do thinks like margin-top:100px; in css in pushes everything up and the item won't go down. So how could I get this item down and so the rest stay the same.

```css
nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  /* material acceleration */
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  will-change: transform;
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
}

nav::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 25em;
  background: #4B6A79;
  content: "";
  transform: skewX(15deg) translateX(-100%);
  transform-origin: bottom left;
  will-change: transform;
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
  opacity: 0.5;
}


/*Dit is breedte van de navigatie gebeuren staat nu op 0*/

@media (min-width: 20em) {
  nav::before {
    width: 0em;
  }
}

nav a {
  margin: 0.5em 0;
  padding: 0.2em 1em;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 500;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  transition: color 0.15s, transform 0.5s;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
}

nav a:nth-child(1) {
  transition-delay: 0s, 100ms;
}

nav a:nth-child(2) {
  transition-delay: 0s, 150ms;
}

nav a:nth-child(3) {
  transition-delay: 0s, 200ms;
}

nav a:nth-child(4) {
  transition-delay: 0s, 250ms;
}

nav a:nth-child(5) {
  transition-delay: 0s, 300ms;
}

nav a:nth-child(6) {
  transition-delay: 0s, 350ms;
}

nav a:hover,
nav a:focus {
  color: lightseagreen;
}

#Afmelden {
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

```html
<nav class="menuclass" id="menu">
  <a href="HomePage.aspx"><img src="Resources/home.png" /></a>
  <a href="HomePage.aspx" target="_blank"><img src="Resources/newtabblad.png" /></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="Resources/game.png" /></a>
  <a href="Login.aspx"><img src="Resources/login.png" /></a>
  <asp:LinkButton class="menuclass" ID="Afmelden" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click">Afmelden</asp:LinkButton>

</nav>
```

I made an ID for the item I wanted to get down it's called 'Afmelden' because I thought that if I would give it an ID that I could get in down because you only select this item.

I tried also to get in outside this nav-bar but that won't work because it wont be visible in the slide in part of the nav bar.

Hope this explains it if not please ask.

Thanks for you help

Comment: Have you tried `#Afmelden { position: relative; top: 100px;}`

Comment: Wow easy fix. It does work because of the position: relative, forgot about that! Thanks you so much!